# Improve Lucene search speed with a hitcollector

Tags: performance, lucene, lucene.net

Is it possible to reduce search time with the use of Lucene's Hitcollector and if so, how would this be properly implemented in the following situation?

```
// search login here ie. 
// this is the search method
// random query
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vendor))
{
   bQuery.Add(qbVendor.Parse(vendor.ToLower()), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
}

bQuery.Add(qbWebsite.Parse(website.ToLower()), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
TopDocs hits = this.ProductIndexSearcher.Search(bQuery, null, 1000)
return hits.scoreDocs;
```

And this part would be the function call:

```
ScoreDoc[] docs = null;
docs = s.KeywordSearch(keyword, category, Webshop.Context.InSiteWebshopId, null, null).ToList(), 1000

foreach (ScoreDoc d in docs.Take(maxResult))
{                                
   Document doc = this.ProductIndexSearcher.Doc(d.doc);
}
```

From what I understand it would not be advisable to get documents from the searchresults using Searcher.Doc but to have a hitcollector. I have tried to get a hitcollector in but ended up with confusion. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
To clarify what I am worried about:

> For good search performance, implementations of this method should not
>   call Searcher.doc(int) or
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.document(int) on every document
>   number encountered. Doing so can slow searches by an order of
>   magnitude or more.

Reference: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/2.9.1/org/apache/lucene/search/HitCollector.java

So I was just wondering if adding an hitcollector would give us some additional performance. If it isn't needed to use a HitCollector when calling Searcher.Search(params) as specified in the first answer, I'm ok. Can u please confirm this?

Answer (score 3):

`HitCollector` is deprecated in 2.9, and completely removed from 3.0. Do not use it.

If you need it you should implement your own `Collector`. This is usually usefull if you want to have the raw results for a search, which are needed for stuff like custom scoring, filtering, etc.

Its not really clear what you are asking for here, but with the code you posted you are not doing anything fancy, and you seem to want "Top n results".

Therefore you should use the TopDocsCollector, which is automatically used by the [Searcher.Search(Query,int)](https://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs//versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int%29) method.

I also recommend you read the doc from the [Searchable.Search(Weight weight, Filter filter, Collector collector)](https://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs//versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Searchable.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Weight,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Collector%29) method:

> Lower-level search API.
>
> Collector.collect(int) is called for every document. Collector-based
>   access to remote indexes is discouraged.
>
> Applications should only use this if they need all of the matching
>   documents. The high-level search API (Searcher.search(Query,int)) is
>   usually more efficient, as it skips non-high-scoring hits.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. From what I understand I do not have to use hitcollector as I am indeed not doing anything fancy after retrieving the docs. I thought that overall collecting the scoredocs could be performance wise improved by using a HitCollector. If this Searcher.Search is already using the hitcollector it seems fine.